# Eclipse Neon - Team Synchronize View - ALL results disappear after pushing "Remove from View" (Not only the selected entries)

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-neon

After the upgrade from Eclipse Mars to Eclipse Neon I have the following problem:

As soon as I push the button "**Remove from View**" at the Eclipse-View "**Synchronize**" all my synchronization results disappear.

I have either to synchronize again or to push the button "Incoming Mode" and after that I have to switch back to the "Outgoing Mode" in order to see my results again. (But all removed entries are back again)

The same phenomenon occurs once I modify the sourcecode at the split screen.

Does anyone know anything about this problem? - Or does anyone know a solution?

I use the following settings:

- Eclipse NEON
- SVN Interface: JavaHL (JNI) 1.8.13(r1667537)
- CollabNet Merge Client (4.1.0)
- jdk8_91 (64bit)

Thank you very much in advance!
Kind regards.

Comment: What are you expecting "Remove from View" to do instead of what it is doing?

Comment: Maybe the heading is misleading ... ALL results disappear instead of only the selected entries from the result list. After that I have to synchronize the project again in order to see all incoming / outgoing files again ... but my modifications got lost.